# How to make concurrent/parallel request to a non idempotent API in AWS Lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, aws-lambda, concurrency

I have an API for which I created a lambda function to hit it on the 1st of every month.

All the steps executed upon hitting the API:

- Fetch all the users having their birthday in current month.
- Create a gift card for each user and save that gift card into the gift card table.
- Send gift codes to the users via mail.

**NOTE:** Each user needs to get a single gift card only.
Another related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72629523/13509950) by me.

Currently In my lamda I used a loop to hit the API(every time gift cards will be sent to only first 100 users and in the next time same query is run those users will not be returned by the query).

Since number of users can be very large I want to make concurrent requests so that lambda doesn't time out.

**Query to fetch users:**
`?` will be replaced with the current year and month

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.email, u.date_of_birth
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN gift_card gc ON
    DATE_FORMAT(gc.scheduled_at, '%Y') = ? AND
    gc.message = 'Happy birthday! from BURST' AND
    gc.status = 1 AND
    gc.recipient_email = u.email
WHERE
    DATE_FORMAT(u.date_of_birth, '%m') = ? AND
    u.email IS NOT NULL AND u.status = 10 AND
    gc.recipient_email IS NULL
LIMIT 100
```

After this I run another query to add gift card in gift table and then send the mail.

Is there any way to achieve this in node? maybe a different service or by using some other technique.

Comment: One way is to start the job in the background and immediately respond with OK to the lambda.

Comment: Do you mean I hit the API only once and let server do its stuff for all the users? Won't it take a lot of resources to process this big query? What to do in case failure occurs?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It seems that you have lots of data to process, so whatever you do will take time, you can't escape it. The only question is how you handle it. With my approach this can be optimized further, by introducing for example a queue and workers (lambda calls api, api creates a "task" and sends it to a queue, a worker picks it up, queries all users, possibly in parallel, and sends each user as a separate "task" to a queue, finally card workers pick users and process them separately). In case of failure you just log the error and/or send a notification.